# Width: x% changing depending on content size

Tags: html, css

I need help to change % width on my category images within my site whenever my screen gets smaller. Or the images will get super small on smaller resolution.

What I want to achieve is something like this: http://www.twitch.tv/directory

I've tried to do this by using this code. (but it isnt working)

```
.category-list-item {
float: left;
@media screen and (max-width: 769px) {width: 20%;};
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {width: 25%;};
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {width: 33.33%;};
padding: 1em;
```

Would be super greatful for any help!

/ Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As rekire says, you messed the syntax,  and you need to set full rules.

Also, there shouldn't be semicolons after the rules. 
And lastly, your 2 final rules cover all the posibilities, width being greater or smaller than 480px, so the first rule will never apply.

I have changed it so that you have an style for lower res, another for higher res, and the default applied in between

```css
.category-list-item {
  background-color:red;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 769px) {
  .category-list-item { background-color: green; }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px)  {
  .category-list-item { background-color: blue; }
}
```

```html
<div class="category-list-item">Test</div>
```